# Matching between multi column and row and return in a cell

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

I am try to find a formula can calculating below results, and I have tried several formula and combination but still fail : ( Anyone can help T^T

Matching A1:F1 within the column A:F, and find:-

- How many cells in each rows were matched with A1:F1? Below table result should be:

  - Row2 have 5 match with A1:F1
  - Row3 have 0 match with A1:F1
  - Row4 have 6 match with A1:F1
  - Row5 have 4 match with A1:F1
  - Row6 have 6 match with A1:F1
- Then count wow many rows have 6/5/4/3/2/1 of 6 match, like:-

  - H1 result is 6/6 match = 2
  - G1 result is 5/6 match = 1
  - I1 result is 4/6 match = 1
- ```
      A   B   C   D   E   F
  1   1   2   3   4   5   6   
  2   2   3   4   5   6   7
  3   8   9   10  11  12  13
  4   1   2   3   4   5   6
  5   3   4   5   6   7   8
  6   1   2   3   4   5   6
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In **G2** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A$1:F$1,A2:F2))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Use  similar formulas to compare different columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, but maybe my question is not clear enough, I used to try sumproduct + countif to calculate the match with A1:F1, but I facing the problem is I need to calculate each row and return this result then calculate how many match for each record, if using countif + sunmproduct, it would using huge formula and need to update the formula manually once new record add, any other simple way to get the result of column H/I/J?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6x2u.jpg)